# Charged for attending public school in the US as a minor on B1

Tags: air-travel

My daughter travelled on a B1/B2 visa in 2014 and stayed with her aunt. She came back to her home country almost 4 years ago to apply for an F1 visa. She was rejected and charged for overstaying and attending a public school.

What can we do to improve her chances of getting her new visa to attend college?

Comment: There’s nothing you can do. Your story is not adding up. Four years ago is 2014 so how long did she stay ther since she went in 2014?

Comment: Did she really apply for an F1 visa 4 years ago, and you are asking now? Or did she come back *after four  years in the US* and now wants to apply for an F1?

Comment: If your daughter left the US after her 18th birthday, her legal situation will depend on how many days she remained in the US after her 18th birthday.

Comment: She was not "charged" -- neither overstaying nor attending a public school is a crime. They are just violations of her B1 status. She may or may not have a ban depending on the exact timeline. But even if she doesn't have a ban, she can be denied a nonimmigrant visa due to the generic reason of "failure to overcome the presumption of immigrant intent", and any negative factor in her history can contribute to the officer's determination.

Comment: Also, B1 is business visa, and it is very unlikely that a minor would be a business visitor. Did you mean B2 instead?